# ServiceBusSender - is it recommended to cache and reuse?

Tags: azureservicebus

We have a component that receives messages and posts them to the service bus.

I'm wondering if it recommended to cache and keep using the same ServiceBusSender or to create and use a new object every time.

```
                _serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(_serviceBus.ConnectionString);
                _serviceBusSender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(Topic);
```

and in the dispose

```
                        _serviceBusSender?.CloseAsync()?.Wait();
                        _serviceBusSender = null;
                        _serviceBusClient?.DisposeAsync().AsTask()?.Wait();
                        _serviceBusClient = null; // should we be caching and re-using _serviceBusSender and _serviceBusClient?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ServiceBusClient` should not be disposed. It keeps the connection object to the broker. Reestablishing connection to the broker is not a cheap operation. Creating senders and receivers with the same client is inexpensive and is ok.